# Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function (Firebase and react-hook-form v7)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hook-form

I am new to React and I am trying to populate the input fields from Firebase with the user information (already given upon sign-up) whenever the user signs in. I already applied the new approach for `react-hook-form-v7` in `input` field:

`<input type="text" name="name" {...register("name")} />`

...but it still shows me error and the field is not populating. Can someone help me solve this issue? Below is my code of the **Profile** page.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSession } from '../firebase/userProvider';
import { firestore } from '../firebase/config';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const Profile = () => {
    const { user } = useSession();
    const params = useParams();
    const { register, setValue } = useForm();
    const [userDocument, setUserDocument] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const docRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(params.id);
        const unsubscribe = docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const documentData = doc.data();
                setUserDocument(documentData);
                const data = Object.entries(documentData).map((entry) => ({
                    [entry[0]]: entry[1]
                }));
                setValue(data);
            }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user.uid, setValue, params.id]);

    if (!userDocument) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div
  className="add-form-container"
  style={{ maxWidth: 960, margin: '50px auto' }}
>
  <form className="ui big form">
    <div className="fields">
      <div className="eight wide field">
        <label>
          Name
          <input type="text" name="name" {...register("name")} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="eight wide field">
        <label>
          Email
          <input type="text" name="email" disabled {...register("email")} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="fields">
      <div className="six wide field">
        <label>
          Address
          <input type="text" name="address" {...register("address")} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="five wide field">
        <label>
          City
          <input type="text" name="city" {...register("city")} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="two wide field">
        <label>
          State
          <input type="text" name="state" {...register("state")} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="three wide field">
        <label>
          Zip
          <input type="text" name="zip" {...register("zip")} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="equal width fields">
      <div className="field">
        <label>
          Phone
          <input type="text" name="phone" {...register("phone")} />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label>
          Specialty
          <select className="specialty" name="specialty" {...register("specialty")} >
            <option value="field agent">Field Agent</option>
            <option value="covert operations">Covert Operations</option>
            <option value="intelligence officer">Intelligence Officer</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label>
          ip
          <input type="text" name="ip" {...register("ip")} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="ui submit large grey button right floated">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>

    )
}

export default Profile;
```

There are also two other files that I hook `useForm` which is **Login** and **Signup** pages. Both are working fine.

Comment: Have you wrapped your Profile component with a Router: (BrowserRouter etc)?

Comment: Also, there might be some problem with circular import. What is the code of '../firebase/userProvider' and '../firebase/config'?